# Spark: Using read.json() to read a very large RDD[String]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark.read.json(RDD) to read in a very large RDD[String] which are in json format.

This is causing OutOfMemory Errors. I have tried increasing executor/driver memory. As well as increasing the num-Executors.

Is there any alternatives to creating a Dataframe from an RDD of JSON strings?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `spark.createDataFrame(RDD)` method and then process the json strings with `sql.functions` methods like `from_json(e: Column, schema: String, options: Map[String, String]): Column`